# How to send list grid data to email using GWT

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

can anyone suggest how to send grid data to email(compose email) using smart gwt/GXT.because i am smart gwt beginer

Comment: Can have a look to: http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/email-utility-class. You have to define your rpc service which will deal will the utilities and manage the data exchange between your client and your server.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll want to take the data in the ListGrid's DataSource and POST it to another handler to accomplish what you'd like to do.  I don't think SmartGWT itself will provide the functionality you're looking for.